# foldLeft on Iterable(String, (Long,Long))

Tags: scala, fold

So. Scenario:

I have this kind of list:

```
("USER1",(24,11))
("USER2",(10,7))
("USER2",(1,10))
("USER1",(2,3))
("USER3",(3,4))
```

and I need to `groupBy` all information of every User, and then sum information of every tuple.

So my expected output is:

```
("USER1",(26,14))
("USER2",(11,17))
("USER3",(3,4))
```

I achieve this with this following code:

```
userInfo.groupBy(elem => elem._1).map(_._2).map { user =>
              {
                val sums = user.foldLeft(("", (0L, 0L)))((acc, newElem) =>
                  (acc._1,
                   (acc._2._1 + newElem._2._1, acc._2._2 + newElem._2._2)))
              }
          (user._1,sums)
       }
```

where `userInfo` is a `Iterable[String,(Long,Long)]`
As you can see, I used a foldLeft, where I pretty much ignore the first element of every tuple, because I don't really care in foldLeft.

I was wondering, because I find it pretty awful code, basically because this `foldLeft` with a empty String, is there a better solution for this?

Comment: Not an answer but it's worth noting that in Cats you can write this as `userInfo.foldMap(Map(_))`.

Comment: @TravisBrown Is Cats a language? or am I too ignorant to understand your comment?

Comment: Sorry—it's [a library for Scala](https://github.com/typelevel/cats) that provides a bunch of abstractions and useful stuff like `foldMap`.

Comment: Specifically `foldMap` says "map a function over the elements of this collection and add up the results at the same time".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mapValues` and a simple `reduce`:

```
val res: Map[String, (Int, Int)] = 
  userInfo
    .groupBy { case (user, _) => user }
    .mapValues { it: Iterable[(String, (Int, Int))] => 
      it
        .map { case (_, tuple) => tuple }
        .reduce[(Int, Int)] { case ((a, b), (c, d)) => (a + c, b + d) } 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this, you can use *reduce* in this case instead of *foldLeft*:

```
def sumOp(x: (Int, Int), y: (Int, Int)): (Int, Int) = (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2)

userInfo.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(user => user.map{ case (u, x) => x }.reduce(sumOp))
// res52: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,(Int, Int)] = Map(USER2 -> (11,17), USER1 -> (26,14), USER3 -> (3,4))
```